# Proving $H$ Is A Subgroup Of $G$

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G=\mathbb{R}^2$ with vectors addition, Prove: $H=\{x,0:x\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a sub group

I am trying to understand the combined condition to prove it is a sub group, I need to take $a,b\in H$ and show that $ab^{-1}\in H$

So If I take $a=(a,0),b=(b,0)$ I need to show that $(a,0)+(-b,0)=(a-b,0)\in H$ but $b^{-1}=(-b,0)$ is in $H$ is it fine or I must take $b^{-1}\in G$ that is not in $H$?

Comment: For all $b\in H$ you must show that $b^{-1}\in H$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one and only requirement on $b$ is that $b\in H$ (and similarily, we need $a\in H$). You then have to show that $ab^{-1}\in H$. This includes the case where you pick $a = e$, which means that $b^{-1}\in H$ is part of what you need to check for any $b\in H$. However, it happens automatically since we pick arbitrary $a$. Separately making sure that $b^{-1}\in H$ before checking that $ab^{-1}\in H$ is unnecessary, and looking for $b^{-1}\in G\setminus H$ to use in the test is entirely irrelevant.

Personally, I prefer to use the full three-property test for subgroups:

- $e\in H$
- for any $a\in H$, we have $a^{-1}\in H$
- for any $a, b\in H$, we have $ab\in H$

The last two points may be condensed into the single test that you are using, but unless everything is completely clear to you, I strongly suggest you use this test instead. There are fewer confusions that way, and it usually takes the same amount of time and space anyways.

Comment: Just to close the issue $(a-b,0)\in H$ and therefore $H$ is a subgroup?

Comment: @gbox Yes. If you've also established that $H$ is non-empty.